# Как создать словарь в dataframe, который будет создавать новые столбцы со значениями по ключу

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, словари

есть основной `DataFrame` (ключ - 6-й столбец A105, A115, A120...):

[image: данные по продажам]

надо к основному dataframe добавить новые столбцы с наименованием клиентов(сети, ОКЕЙ и т.д.). Источником к формированию столбцов с наименованием клиентов является справочник клиентов:

[image: справочник клиентов]

Полагаю, что это делается через словарь, но как оформить в `DataFrame` не могу понять.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

Исходные DataFrame'ы:

```
In [188]: d1
Out[188]:
     ID  Val
0  A105  222
1  A105  555
2  A120  333
3  A130  444

In [189]: d2
Out[189]:
     ID      Name      Info
0  A105  Name_105  Info_105
1  A120  Name_120  Info_120
2  A130  Name_130  Info_130
3  A140  Name_140  Info_140
```

Решение:

```
res = d1.merge(d2, on='ID')
```

Результат:

```
In [191]: res
Out[191]:
     ID  Val      Name      Info
0  A105  222  Name_105  Info_105
1  A105  555  Name_105  Info_105
2  A120  333  Name_120  Info_120
3  A130  444  Name_130  Info_130
```